# What is the maximum debuglevel for a Python httplib

Tags: python, httplib

[These docs](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httpconnection-objects) do not say what the maximum debug level is.

I need to know that.

Answer (score 11):

I went through httplib.py and the code is littered with the following statement:

```
if self.debuglevel > 0:
```

This means there are just two levels.

1. debuglevel less than or equal to zero
2. debuglevel greater than zero

Yes this could have been better documented.

Also any time you need to check such an information, you can easily look at the code.
`Here is my favorite approach to locate a source file for a particular module.`

```
>>> import httplib
>>> httplib.__file__
'/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.pyc'
```

Now you can just open the following file to go through it's source code

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py
```

Comment: "Yes this could have been better documented." Agreed. Thanks for answering this.

Answer (score 2):

As I saw from *httplib.py* sources there are only 2 debug levels:

- <=0 - no debug info
- any value greater than zero - turn on debug info

This is a typical check:

```
if self.debuglevel > 0:
        print "blablabla"
```